# Insert into one table base on join result from 2 other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables in  MySQL: def_table,spot_table,tag_mapping_spot_table.

```
def_table

tag_id       tag_ja
2010490043   アラバマ・アンド・ガルフ・コースト鉄道
2010680003   american_football、サッカー、スポーツ
2010970036   ノーフォークマツの種
.........    ..........

spot_table

spot_id   spot_name
1          NULL  
2          NULL
3          NULL
...        ....

tag_mapping_spot_table

spot_id   tag_id
1         2010490043 
2         2010680003
3         2010970036
....      .....
```

All I want to do is join "tag_mapping_spot_table" and "def_table" base on column tag_id  and then join the result with "spot_table" base on spot_id.I want to put the result from column tag_ja to column spot_name

Some thing like

```
insert into spot(spot_name) where spot_id = b.spot_id
(select a.tag_ja,b.spot_id from def_table a join tag_mapping_spot b 
on a.tag_id = b.tag_id
```

Here is the result I want in spot_table

```
spot_id   spot_name
1         アラバマ・アンド・ガルフ・コースト鉄道 
2         american_football、サッカー、スポーツ
3         ノーフォークマツの種
```

Comment: I think you need a `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. It depends if the table `spot_table` is filled (with `spot_id`) or empy

Comment: Kai do you want to update the existing rows or add new rows?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I want to update the existing rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `UPDATE` (not `INSERT`): 
[UPDATE DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

```
 UPDATE spot_table ST 
 INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot_table c ON c.spot_id = ST.spot_id 
 INNER JOIN def_table b ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id 
 SET ST.spot_name = b.tag_ja
```

Comment: I  got an error in MySQL syntax under the word "FROM" . Still finding why it's not working

Comment: The code should work, add **AS** on `FROM spot_table AS ST`

Comment: I think we should change position 2 inner join sentences ```UPDATE spot_table ST
INNER JOIN tag_mapping_spot_table c ON c.spot_id = ST.spot_id
INNER JOIN def_table b ON b.tag_id = c.tag_id   SET ST.spot_name = b.tag_ja```