# Update table with values from another table - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an account and customer tables which can be linked by customer `col` and get the date `col` to the account table.

**account table**:

[image]

**customer table**:

[image]

**final table**:

[image]

If I use the below query, I am getting following **error**

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

What am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE account
SET date = (
SELECT date
FROM customer
WHERE customer.customer = account.customer
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into one table base on join result from 2 other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391336/insert-into-one-table-base-on-join-result-from-2-other-table) **(see the accepted answer)**

Comment: @Roy, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `update ... join ... set` syntax:

```
update account a
inner join customer c on a.customer = c.custom
set a.date = c.date
```